# Google Maps showing different address than business location

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been trying to help an optometrist in Florida with a location error. The store is optical outlets in Ocoee, FL at 9428 W Colonial Dr.

When you search for optical outlets in ocoee on maps you will notice it is located south of W colonial drive in a shopping center next to a Thai restaurant: goo.gl/0EJjX3

However, when you type in the address of the store, 9428 W Colonial Dr, Ocoee, FL 34761, by itself, without the business name, directly into google maps, the listing shows it is in the mall about half a mile away.
Some elderly and disabled patients are being driven to the mall and left there and it's causing lots of problems. Google My business cannot help me. Submitting feedback to google mpas directly, multiple times over 5 months has proven fruitless.

Any suggestions??

I am at a loss.

Thank you!

Image: [The top highlight is the address of the store as it appears on google without the name of the business attached. The bottom highlight is where the store is actually located.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgLmS.jpg)

Comment: Can you display the code witch you are using for? We can not (or difficulty) help you without your code.

Answer (score 0):

From your description I can understand that you are facing a data issue on maps.google.com and sending feedback didn't work.

In this case the unique option for you is filing a data issue in the Google issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188875&template=788017

I hope this helps!